# How to find a value if we have 2 same columns in 2 different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

As you can see on the photo. I have 2 tables(A and B). **KlantId** is common in 2 tables. What I want to achieve is, if I provide the **Email** then I can get the **reservatieNummer**.[image]

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text... Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: what have u done so far ? have u tried join 2 tables with common id selecting email ?

Comment: @jarlh you can click on the image

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.reservatieID 
from tablea as a
inner join tableb as b on a.KlantId = b.KlantId 
where a.email="whatever"
```

and you specify the email in the where condition

Comment: Glad it helped! if it solved the issue, can you also accept the answer (green tick)? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To use linq:

```
var ReservatieID =  tableA.Join(tableB, ta =>ta.KlantId, tb =>tb.KlantId, (ta,tb) =>new{tableA = ta, tableB = tb})
                    .Where(a=> a.email == "whatever@domain.com").Select(a=> new{a.reservatieID});
```